# How do I get around a GeneralName TypeError?

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to get into writing code to scrape stock web pages, I came across this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BrpKpWwT2A. When I copy and paste the following code (from the video)

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use("ggplot")
start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

df = web.DataReader("TSLA", "yahoo", start, end)
print(df.head())
```

I still get the same error (Full traceback is too long to add here) but the last few lines say:

```
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 363, in getpeercert
    'subjectAltName': get_subj_alt_name(x509)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 213, in get_subj_alt_name
    ext = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/utils.py", line 170, in inner
    result = func(instance)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py", line 127, in extensions
    self._backend, self._x509

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py", line 252, in parse
    value = handler(backend, ext_data)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py", line 438, in _decode_subject_alt_name
    _decode_general_names_extension(backend, ext)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 1262, in __init__
    self._general_names = GeneralNames(general_names)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 1217, in __init__
    "Every item in the general_names list must be an "

TypeError: Every item in the general_names list must be an object conforming to the GeneralName interface
```

Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: First, I would recommend leaving the full traceback, not only the exception. That would help.

Comment: Hi, apologies as I'm new to the site. I tried to add the full traceback but it says that my question contained too much code, the last few lines of it are as follows:         
`
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 1217, in __init__
    "Every item in the general_names list must be an "

TypeError: Every item in the general_names list must be an object conforming to the GeneralName interface` (I'll edit the question to include it as it looks messy here)

Comment: I need to see the full traceback to know what you are doing and where the error is coming from

Comment: It might be related to anaconda installation.

Comment: It was to do with the installation... I updated anaconda to the latest version and now the code works! Thank-you @wonderwhy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above code and got the following output:

[image]

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for contributing to the question. However, this is not an answer to it. You should leave these notes in the comment box.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!! I was not able to upload an image of the output in the comment so had to post as the answer!

Comment: I understand. There are other ways you can do it. You can use upload services and leave a link to the image. Your answer might get flagged/downvoted as it really does not answer the question, regardless of whether the question is correct.

Comment: Cool! Thank you, will follow that.

Comment: Thanks for answering, everyone else on the videos comments seemed to be getting that as an output as-well, I'm not sure what a generalname error is or why I seem to be the only one getting it :(